# How to go to username prompt while using SCP command in a loop(Python script)

Tags: python

i have a loop as below:

```
if (num>0):

  user = raw_input("Enter your username : ")
  username = user.split()

  os.system("scp priyo.py" + username[0] + "@" + l[i] + ".win.com:/var/tmp")
```

Here, l[i] is a list of hostnames from a text file. In each iteration of the loop it will read a single hostname and will process it.

So, whenever i am entering a wrong username it asks for password 3 times and then it starts processing for the next hostname from the text file. I want that it should again ask for username before going to the next hostname so that i can enter the correct username.

Please help with some idea.

Comment: Don't use `os.system`; use `subprocess.call`; you can use control-c to kill the process; check the exit code of the process; if it is non-zero, you can ask for another username.

Comment: I tried with something like:

Answer (score 0):

os.system returns the exit status of the command, I believe (but didn't test) scp will return non-zero if operation failed, then you can prompt something like "scp failed, wanna retry?".